# How to pass arguments to a child class

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement, fifo

Basically I want to have 4 classes where I want to choose each of the four classes randomly according to a random number generator.The parent class has all the functions and I want to be able to have 3 other child classes to be the same function as the parent class

```
class Job:
    ......(all the code over here)....

class Job2(Job):
    pass
class Job3(Job):
    pass
class Job4(Job):
    pass 

for i in range 4:  
    a=randint(0,4)
    if a==1:
        Job
    if a==2:
        Job2
    if a==3:
        Job3
    if a==4:
        Job4
```

The whole point of this is to reduce the "waiting time" (this is basically a FIFO simulation) by a quarter. I thought that by doing random and iterating it 4 times it would go over the Jobs 4 times in iteration

How do I call a Job in a function?

Comment: How does your class setup relate to the random part? Which part is your question about? Aside from formatting, your classes are fine. The random part is fine in principle, it just not do *anything* with the selected class.

Comment: I want it to be such that if a==1(for example) the parent class gets activated. If a==3 Job3 gets activated and this happens over an iteration so random numbers between 0 and 4 are produced iteratively and thus selecting each Job by itself

Comment: What do you mean by "the class gets activated"? You are already selecting the classes properly, you just don't do anything - assign them, instantiate them - with them. What do you want to *do* with the selected class, and what specific problem do you have with that?

Answer (score -1):

Can be refined, but main ideas on this are that when you implement `__call__` as a method of a class, the instantiated object can be called as a function.

(`jobs[a]()` instantiates the job, and then you call the result of this operation as a function).

```
from random import randint

class Job:
    def __init__(self, id=0):
        self.id = id

    def __call__(self):
        print(self.id)

class Job1(Job):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1

class Job2(Job):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 2

class Job3(Job):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 3

a=randint(0, 3)
jobs = [Job, Job1, Job2, Job3]
job = jobs[a]()

job()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the that but what I don't get the id part.

Comment: Hi :) It's just an attribute id common to all jobs so I could print it on the `__call__` method, when you call the `job()`.

Comment: If you execute this code each time it will random select a job between 0 and 3.

Comment: (and print the id).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. My assignment is basically to stimulate a FIFO queue and in this have four servers working together.

Comment: I've omitted the outer loop in my answer. You want to call every Job in sequence is that it ? Like Job() then Job1() then Job2() ... ?

Comment: The class Job has a whole process to it which I haven't shown in the code above. Basically data comes in at random time intervals and this can either go into one of the four classes at random to reduce queue time

Comment: Using `randint` won't prevent that the same Job is randomly selected many times in sequence, "starving" others.

Comment: It's an assignment so if you get the whole solution ready you won't learn much. You should first implement a feature that combines `randint` with a pick feature so that on each "round" you pick all servers randomly one time each (so that for instance the random pick doesn't select one job by accident many times instead of idle others)

Comment: You are right about the randint part. What should I use?(I'm very new to Python so please forgive my ignorance)

Comment: This is a very good random drawing code: https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/05-1class-func/bingocall.py DON'T just run it without understanding what it does, because you won't learn anything.